# JSON - Building Json Dynamically

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to build my json dynamically but cant seem to get the results within the dynamic object to store the values:

```
    public class CDJson : JObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string style { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
    }
    public class CDColsJson : JObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string style { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
        public int xsCol { get; set; }
        public int smCol { get; set; }
        public int mdCol { get; set; }
        public int lgCol { get; set; }
    }

    public string Build_CDSectionJson(string id, string style, string @class)
    {
        dynamic cdSection = new JObject();
        cdSection.section = new Constants.CDJson() { id = id, style = style, @class = @class };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cdSection); // WHERE THE VALUES ARE EMPTY

        return json;
    }
```

Code:

```
    var CD_Section = build.Build_CDSectionJson(sectionGUID, "", "sectioncon")
```

Output:

```
    {"section":{}}
```

I am passing some values but they are empty, what am i doing wrong?

I tried this:

```
    dynamic cdSection = new JObject();
    cdSection.section.id = id;
    cdSection.section.style = style;
    cdSection.section.@class = @class;
```

But came back as null.

Comment: Why would you inherit JObject? That may be why. Also take a look at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm

Comment: i need the json like this {"section":{ "id" : "dgdhdjhf", "style" : "somestyle", "class" : "someclass" }}. how would i achieve this?

Comment: You should not make `cdSection` a `dynamic` or assign arbitrary C#-type properties to it. If you want to add a property to a `JObject`, use `cdSection.Add("section", theValue)`

Comment: Also, what is it that you're actually trying to do here? Why not define a class that has a `section` property of type `CDJson`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks JLRishe

This worked great:

```
    JObject cdSectionAttr = new JObject();
    cdSectionAttr.Add("id", id);
    cdSectionAttr.Add("style", style);
    cdSectionAttr.Add("@class", @class);

    JObject cdSection = new JObject();
    cdSection.Add("section", cdSectionAttr);
```